# Sitecore Allow Specific Role to Write to only Specific Fields

Tags: permissions, sitecore, roles, sitecore8

I want to only allow write access to certain fields for a role. There is one template with all the fields that this role should be able to write to. This role should still be able to read all other fields on any item though.

Just to try it, I copied the raw value generated when field write access is denied and that is applied to all descendants and pasted that in the security field for a template folder that holds all the templates used on the site but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `Security Editor` to set `Field Write` permissions for the role you require.

[image: Allow Write]

Also you would need to set `Deny Field Write` for other users / roles.

[image: Deny Write]

You can check your permissions are as you expect via the `Access Viewer` as you configure the Security settings, both tools are in the `Security Tools` menu item

[image]

You would need to have `Field Write` available on the `Security Editor` you can do this via the `Columns` option.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a scalable way so that adding new templates won't require each dev to know specific permissions to apply to new template fields. I think I'm going to write a worker method that goes through the template tree and sets permissions to deny field write access to all items except the one that role needs to be able to write to. It seems way over the top to me though.

Comment: Denying write access to a template doesn't deny editing the fields on the instances of that template from what I'm seeing. I can't actually assign field write access at the template level either. When I did this by selecting raw values and pasting in what should deny field write from the item and its descendants nothing happened. I'm going to go through each field and set it there.